# SVG <image> element rendering quality

Tags: html, css, svg, html-rendering, image-quality

I have a SVG canvas which user can select and resize some `<image>` elements inside. And I use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` attribute value to keep the original aspect ratio. The original image sources are mostly `256x256px` size. On Firefox and IE-11, when I resize `<image>` elements to a smaller size than their original size, they look very pixelated. On Chrome they look pretty smooth. I wonder if there are any css or svg features which could help me to make them look smoother on Firefox and IE too.

Thank you.

**EDIT: Adding sample..**

https://jsfiddle.net/p8km6nhc/7/

```
<svg viewBox="-170 -87 1678 869" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: -0.800003px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="varlikItemShadow1">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="SourceGraphic"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dy="1" dx="1"></feOffset>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,158,256)">
                <g title="" data-original-title="" data-rounded="yes">
                    <text style="font:0px arial;" x="0" y="1" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0.111111">[[VarlikId=3999]]</text>
                    <rect filter="url(#varlikItemShadow1" stroke="#2b5987" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.9" fill="#ffe8f6" ry="10" rx="10" y="0" x="0" height="140" width="1270"></rect>
                    <path d="M0 0 L 1268 0 1268 138 0 138Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="none" fill-opacity="0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"></path>
                    <image image-rendering="optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" x="14" y="14" width="1242px" height="66px" xlink:href="https://deviantshare.azurewebsites.net/img/test.png"></image>
                    <text style="font:32px arial;" x="0" y="30" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,591,94)" fill="#2b5987">3. Kat</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**RESULT :**

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: your sample refers to an image with a relative link - could you put the image somewhere it can be accessed? Or maybe inline it with something like http://duri.me/

Comment: @learningloop I've edited the sample.

Comment: @CupawnTae I've edited the sample.

Comment: One correction i came across is; instead of stretching the image with `width` attribute to bring it to center, you can change `x` attribute like the following `x="600px" y="14" width="66px" height="66px"`. This is not an answer.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, but a CSS one : on FF41&43, when `image-rendering` is set to `optimizequality`, it's actually the crisp-edges algo which is used, `<image>` element doesn't seem to be affected by this css rule at all : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8km6nhc/10/)

Comment: @Kaiido I think the "image-rendering" attribute on a svg `<image>` element and the "image-rendering" css property are two different things. There is a reference here on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/image-rendering) for svg, it says it can be applied to only `<image>` elements. And on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) for css reference, it says the values used to be the same with svg reference, but they are changed with new ones later on...

Comment: Can't check right now, but I think that CSS rules should also apply to `<image>` element. Anyway, svg's `image-rendering` property doesn't have any effect, which is a bug. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8km6nhc/11/)

Comment: hum that's it, from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/image-rendering) "As a presentation attribute, it also can be used as a property directly inside a CSS stylesheet, see css image-rendering for further information"

Answer (score 1):

As it clearly looks like an issue with Firefox and IE rendering, thought of trying a workaround to come over this.

Instead of using `<image>` element of SVG, tried using `<img>` tag of HTML and embedded it using `<foreignObject>` element of SVG.

Instead of :

```
<image image-rendering="optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
x="14" y="14" width="1242px" height="66px" 
xlink:href="https://deviantshare.azurewebsites.net/img/test.png"></image>
```

Used:

```
  <foreignObject x="600" y="14" width="100" height="100">
    <body>
      <img src="https://deviantshare.azurewebsites.net/img/test.png" 
       type="image/svg+xml" width="66px" height="66px">
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
```

But one pending issue is [IE doesn't support foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) yet!

Codepen.io working [example](http://codepen.io/learningloop/full/JYYRZG/)

Comment: I can not use `<foreignobject>`... Just as you mentioned, IE doesn't support it unfortunately. If it was supported in IE, I would be able to use foreignobject for whole the content of the box shapes, since text alignment things are also a very big torture in svg..

Comment: @Noldor, if all your pngraphics are like the one in the example, why don't you make them svg already ? You won't have any support or rendering problem, and it may even end in lighter file sizes.